# What is the order of classes when using decision_function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Assume the targets of a multi-class classification problem are `T1, T2, T3`, then the result of `clf.decision_function(X)` given a trained classifier, would be a matrix where the rows are the observations and the columns are the scores for each class.

It is not clear from the documentation (e.g. [for LinearSVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function)) what is the order of the columns. Some experiments suggest that they are lexicographically ordered. Is that correct?

I created a [minimal example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U4v2wr9TM55ltu2QEHna1iLpH2xmpHJl) where it is demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

The order is the same as that provided by the `classes_` attribute.

Behind the scenes, `classes_` is the output of `np.unique(y)` which "Returns the sorted unique elements of an array". In your case `iris_y` is the numerical encoding of `array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')` as provided by the iris dataset.

Comment: In particular, if I get it right, it happen during [fitting](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/354c8c3bc3e36c69021713da66e7fa2f6cb07756/sklearn/svm/classes.py#L231). Is that correct? Is it appearing somewhere in the docs? Can you include some references in your answer?

Comment: @Dror Yes you are correct. During `fit()`, all the unique classes are extracted and based on the number of classes, the other parts are handled, like binary vs multiclass classification, the shape of `coef_` , `intercept_`, `decision_function()` etc.

Comment: Is it a known fact well presented in the docs which I missed?